# Web Service return html asmx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, iis, iis-8

I have this strange problem:
I've made a VB.Net Web Service, and if i call it from Browser (http://localhost/ws.asmx/MethodName) it works and return the XML.
But if i call it from other programs (also SoapUi), the call returns the html of the page .asmx (when i open it from browser, with the list os f Seb Services).
It's a public WebService, with authorization, allow users="*", and only on ii8, on other versions of iis it works.
Why?

Comment: Any more info you can provide? I worked with those for a long time, and I tried really hard to understand/guess, but that's too little information. Could it a bunch of little things: e.g. file-extension mapping in IIS, possibly some web.config settings, maybe even app-pool misconfig or .net presence on that machine or within IIS. Do other .net handlers work on that same website (e.g. aspx)?

Comment: .aspx works, and also an other .asmx NOT PUBLIC works.

Comment: I've just discoverd that using a virtual application that uses the same physical path, the call of the WS works, soapui return the xml.